# Set values of array as a key SERVER PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this:

```
[0] => MFG Part Number: M402TM
[1] => SKU: dd32
[2] => Weight: 2.99lb/1.36kg
[3] => Warranty: 2
```

I want to have array like this:

```
[MFG Part Number] => M402TM
[SKU] => dd32
[Weight] => 2.99lb/1.36kg
[Warranty] => 2
```

And I did it using this code:

```
$new_array = array_reduce($normal_array, function ($c, $v){ 
    preg_match('/^([^:]+):\s+(.*)$/', $v, $m); 
    if(!empty($m[1])){
        return array_merge($c, array($m[1] => $m[2]));}
    else{
        return array();
    }
},[]);
```

This works great locally, but when I open my script on my server, there is a problem, maybe because of different version of PHP or something, I've got error like this

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /location.php on line 322

That is this part of code

```
},[]);
```

Any help? Maybe code that I'm using isn't good? Is there any replecment code for it?

Comment: Shorthand array syntax `[ ]` was introduced in php 5.4. I'm assuming your server has an older version. Either update php on the server or use the long-form array syntax e.g `array( )`

Comment: so have you checked PHP versions on the local and remote servers?

Comment: On my local is 7, i dont know how i can check it on server?

Comment: well, try to use `phpinfo()`

Comment: [function `phpversion()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php)

Comment: developing on php 7.0 and running on lower than 5.4 is going to make more problems like this, you better upgrade PHP on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cant upgrade php version, then use the old array() style:

```
$new_array = array_reduce($normal_array, function ($c, $v){ 
    preg_match('/^([^:]+):\s+(.*)$/', $v, $m); 
    if(!empty($m[1])){
        return array_merge($c, array($m[1] => $m[2]));}
    else{
        return array();
    }
},array());
```

Comment: this works.....